# Bitwise AND with decimal and hex

Tags: bit-manipulation

I want to know if I am doing bitwise AND in a right way.

If we have:

```
231 & 0xFB7F
```

I am doing the following:

```
11100111 & 1111101101111111 = 1100111
```

is it correct?

Comment: Internally it's all just binary numbers. Decimal and hex are just different ways to input and output them with humans, they don't affect the calculations.

Comment: No, a bitwise and takes binary representation of equal length. [**See Widipedia for Details**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). Otherwise -- what is the result of `the bits that don't exist & those that do`? You can `zero extend` the smaller number and correct the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct!
`231 in decimal = 1110 0111 in binary = 0000 0000 1110 0111` in binary (shown in 4-bit group for convenience)

```
0xFB7F in hex = 1111 1011 0111 1111
```

When you do bit wise-AND this becomes

```
0000 0000 0110 0111 in binary
= 67 in deciomal
```